# How to continue execution of fabricate based software when error is encountered

Tags: python-2.7, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, xpath-2.0

There is a tool which uses fabricate makefile and saxon as XSLT processor to  run and build xslt based project. The program is executed using a main python script which executes several files. I have an issue that the python script is stopping when an error is encountered (for example if there is a syntax error in xsl template file, the error comes on screen and execution is stopped). I want the file to execute even when there is an error and log the error into file. I know how to log error into file but i dont know how to continue the execution of program even when error is encountered. Please answer to this question with example because it will be difficult to understand only theory.

Comment: Python has many ways to call non-python programs - it even has many ways to call them via their command line interface - and the first thing we will need to know is which of these mechanisms your script is using. If it's calling Saxon via a command-line interface, then Saxon will return a non-zero return code if errors are encountered, and your Python script will need to handle these appropriately.

Comment: I was able to handle this issue using fabricate error (try: except: statement).

Comment: @MichaelKay I would like to create saxon API for python just like it exists for saxon/C. If you like to extent your product api to python, please do let me know. I am a software expert in python. During project development i have found that it is really useful to have saxon API in python. If you would like me to work on the saxon API creation for python, it will be honor for me :) . Creation of API will give more control of errors and exceptions of saxon.

Comment: We would certainly welcome interfaces to other languages built on top of Saxon/C - we've been doing PHP ourselves, but we're happy to leave others to third parties. Please get in touch direct, this isn't the right forum to discuss this.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for response. Could you please provide your email id so that i can get in touch direct. My email ID is anshulmttl@gmail.com

Comment: You'll find contact information on www.saxonica.com